# Get File from device while debugging

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager

I am creating a application in which I am writing dictionary in a plist file using device. I need that file in my Mac. As if I use simulator I can access my document dir coz this is accessible. How can get that file in my mac or my code while I am using device and application is in debug mode.

Please help me
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable `UIFileSharingEnabled` in your **Info.plist** file. Then, copy the plist to **Documents** folder. The file will be accessible in iTunes Apps tab, File Sharing section. Copy it to your Mac using Export button or just drag and drop to a folder.

To copy the file you can start with this code that will copy the original plist to a new file with a timestamp, to make easier to analyze different copies of the file:

```
/* ARC */
NSURL plistURL = <# original plist #>
NSString *documents = 
[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"];
NSString *path = [documents stringByAppendingFormat:@"/TheFile-%@.plist", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
NSError    *error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:plistURL 
                                                 toURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] 
                                                 error:&error]) {
    /* copy failed */
} else {
    /* ok */
}
```

Comment: They may have rearranged iTunes since 2011. Now (v. 11.0.2) you have to select your device from the (in-window) menu bar, *then* select Apps. File Sharing is at the bottom of the page.

Comment: For the rest of us: UIFileSharingEnabled means adding a key titled “Application supports iTunes file sharing” to you app name-Info.plist file